# Articles about Weil cohomology theory by Grothendieck and Artin

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-k-theory, motives, algebraic-cycles

In *"The Standard Conjectures"* Kleiman says that the following properties of Weil cohomology theory were proved in 1963 for étale cohomology by Artin and Grothendieck, except for the last one that it was proved in 1973 by Deligne.

> "... (1) (finiteness), (2) (Poincaré duality), (3) (Künneth formula), (4) (cycle map), (5) (weak Lefschetz theorem), (6) (strong Lefschetz theorem)..."

Which are the articles where I can find the proofs of this properties?

Comment: Milne's  book on etale cohomology is a good source. He also has a slightly different free version on his web page. If you read French, then there is SGA41/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Milne, Étale cohomology (book and online version)
- Lei Fu, Étale cohomology theory (essentially an English translation of SGA)
- Freitag-Kiehl, Etale cohomology and the Weil conjecture